# Axios post request return failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am using fetch() for login it working fine  but when I want to use `axios` it return failed and also throw an error `from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` . I want to replace fetch() data with axios could someone please help me

```
    (async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${config.apiPath}/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: data.email, password: data.password })
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})()
```

Comment: show us the code using `axios`

Comment: I want to convert it into axios

Comment: does the server have `cors` enabled?

Comment: yes............

Comment: maybe it isn't configured correctly on the server side, this error is nothing to do with client side.